# No POM for multimodule project

Tags: jenkins, maven-2

While releasing a project I am getting below error in jenkins. I have multimodule project where one directory contains 5 projects and each project has its own pom.xml. I have created a 6th project to create EAR ( using 5 projects binaries) and this ear needs to be checked in repository.

**The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/dev/shm/jenkinsworkspaces/Project_EAR_Build/workspace/Project_EAR_Build/target/checkout.). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.**

I have specify goal in jenkins job as **-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform**.

What should I mention in goal so that maven will refer **checkout/EAR_Project** directory to locate
 pom.xml instead of checkout directory ?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you verified that myGITServer is actually a resolvable host name?

Comment: @AlBlue . That issue is resolved . I was using my id for the build instead of functional id ( for which ssh key is setup ). Now I am facing another issue. I have updated the question.